# assigning variable strings too an array with C

Tags: c, arrays, string, cs50

The goal of my code is to have the user, put in any amount of students as an integer and then have the program ask over and over to set a name too every integer (student)

I've been trying so many different things and I've been working on this without using any outside help for hours but I just couldn't figure this out.   (if its something obvious, please don't get supermad, I'm only a beginner)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("How many students are there? ");
    int amount = atoi(GetString());
    printf("amount = %i\n", amount);    
    char *names[amount];

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the ellement #%d :", i +1);
        scanf("%s", names[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i == 0;)
    {
        printf("Acces student: ");
        string search = GetString();
        int searchnr = atoi(search);
        printf("Student #%d is %s\n", searchnr, names[searchnr]);
    }   
}

>

}
```

Comment: Your `*names[amount]` is not valid. You have to allocate memory for this.

Comment: in the CS50 library (it's an online course) it just gets a string from the user and saves it as one. I don't know why they did it, probably to make it easier for them to correct things (or so that we don't have to mess with standardin and on or something?)

Comment: but Dont I allocate memory for the     *names[amount]    
using     int amount = atoi(GetString());

Comment: @LouieWouters You allocate an array of pointers. The pointers are not initialized, though (they don't point to allocated memory). BTW, if you've got the `GetString()` function, why don't you use it? `names[i] = GetString();` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant YES, that worked!! thank you so much, I didn't realise names[i] = ... would assign something too i, thank you so much!

Comment: Note that using `atoi(GetString())` leaks memory.  You should free the string returned by `GetString()` before exiting.  In this size of program, the damage is minimal to non-existent, but now is the time to pick up the good habits — and freeing allocated memory when you're done with it is definitely a good habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    printf("Enter element #%d: ", i + 1);
    names[i] = GetString();
}
```

As to the second loop: it's an infinite loop. What is the terminating condition? You need to put that into the condition of the `for` loop else it will never terminate.

If your intent **is** getting an infinite loop, then a more readable, less confusing, more idiomatic solution is

```
while (1) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
for (;;) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: also thank you for indeed pointing out the obvious! this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to reserve space for those strings:

```
char *names[amount];
char s[100];

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the ellement #%d :", i +1);
    scanf("%s", s);
    names[i] = strdup(s);
}
```

or

```
char *names[amount];
char s[100];
size_t len;

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the ellement #%d :", i +1);
    scanf("%s", s);
    len = strlen(s);
    names[i] = malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy(names[i], s);
}
```

And this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i == 0;)
```

does nothing, what do you want to do? (if you want to loop forever you can use `for(;;)`)

Comment: i know about the for loop, that was just temporary to keep repeating itself

@Alter Mann so I cant have the user define something himself as "s"?

Comment: @LouieWouters If you do want an infinite loop, it's more idiomatic to go with `while (1)` or `for (;;)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `malloc`

```
char temp[50];
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the ellement #%d :", i +1);
    scanf("%s", temp);
    names[i]=malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
    strcpy(names[i],temp);
}
```

Using `strdup`

```
char temp[50];

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
printf("Enter the ellement #%d :", i +1);
scanf("%s", temp);
names[i] = strdup(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your answers were great guys, but this was the final solution:

---

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("How many students are there? ");
    int amount = atoi(GetString()); 
    char *names[amount];

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the ellement #%d :", i +1);
        names[i + 1] = GetString();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i == 0;)
    {
        printf("Acces student: ");
        int search = atoi(GetString());
        printf("Student #%d is %s\n", search, names[search]);
    }   
}
```

and I know I have an infinite loop there, that was just temporary so I don't have to rerun the command all the time.